# JQuery hover tabular design animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was going through this website and I found out this very nice animation in `Compatibility` section.

http://html5css3templates.com/themes/taketheplunge/templates/index.html#about

I am trying to implement it. Hover on section, change the design is I know. But still I am unable to design something like that. Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: You can take a look at the code for the website in developer tools in any browser. Press F12 and it will open a hendy window where you will be able to see any javascript/css/html that is relevant.

Comment: Google 'CSS animations'. You aren't going to learn anything if we just give you the ready-made code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The effects shown are using css3 transitions. `transition` property on `bar class` determines the speed of effect. The hover css does the rest

```
.bar{
    transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.compatibility:hover .percent80 {
    width: 80%;
}
```

checkout [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pDX62/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Stylesheet : http://html5css3templates.com/themes/taketheplunge/templates/css/layout.css
And look at the section concerning the overlays:

```
.brideOverlay {
    border: 5px solid rgba(242, 168, 181, 0.9);
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(242, 168, 181, 0.3) inset;
    width: 420px;
    height: 420px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    position: absolute;
}
.brideOverlay h2{
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 190px;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
    transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out 0s;
}
etc...
```

This is some CSS3 code, so have a look at the [CSS3 intro](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_intro.asp).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I wonder why I didn't check that. :(

Comment: Lol I have just realized that my answer does not answer your question in fact x).

Comment: Both have answered the question. So I upgraded your's and selected his. :). If you want I will make it other way round. ;-)

Comment: No that's cool , thanks for the up, good luck with your project